# PL/SQL wrapper dbms_metadata.get_ddl

Tags: oracle, plsql, procedure

When an application team submits database changes, my group implements them and we send back a copy of the objects using expdp, which is cumbersome because that just initiates another call to our group if a team wants the data from the .dump file.

I've decided to give all application teams a procedure and wrapper so they can see the objects with getting my team involved.

In my test case I can manually extract the ddl when I hardcode the VALUES. When I try and automate the process with a wrapper I am getting the following error.

ORA-00942: table or view does not exist ORA-06512: at "SYS.DBMS_METADATA", line 6731

I can't seem to resolve this issue and was hoping someone can please explain my problem and show me how to fix it.

Below is my test case.  I'm testing with livesql in case anyone wants to duplicate my environment. Thanks in advance for your expertise and all who answer.

```
PLSQL wrapper dbms_metadata.get_ddl

CREATE TABLE my_table
(
   n   DATE,
   s   VARCHAR2 (100),
   d   DATE
);

-- THIS WORKS 

BEGIN
   DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line (
      DBMS_METADATA.get_ddl ('TABLE', 'MY_TABLE'));
END;

CREATE TABLE "SQL_FVHMKYHCKTZSWYEAXJVFNSPQO"."MY_TABLE" 
   (    "N" DATE, 
    "S" VARCHAR2(100) COLLATE "USING_NLS_COMP", 
    "D" DATE
   )  DEFAULT COLLATION "USING_NLS_COMP" SEGMENT CREATION DEFERRED 
  PCTFREE 10 PCTUSED 40 INITRANS 1 MAXTRANS 255 
 NOCOMPRESS LOGGING
  TABLESPACE "LIVESQL_USERS"


-- procedure creates 

CREATE  OR REPLACE PROCEDURE get_metadata(
p_object_type VARCHAR2, 
p_object_name VARCHAR2) authid current_user is
      x clob;
    begin
      x := 
dbms_metadata.get_ddl(
p_object_type,
p_object_name);
    end;   
/

-- sql in wrapper returns data

SELECT OBJECT_TYPE,
OBJECT_NAME,
OWNER
FROM ALL_OBJECTS 
WHERE OWNER LIKE 'SQL%'
AND OBJECT_TYPE IN ('TABLE', 'INDEX', 'FUNCTION', 'PROCEDURE', 'TYPE','PACKAGE', 'SEQUENCE') 

OBJECT_TYPE    OBJECT_NAME    OWNER
TABLE    MY_TABLE    SQL_FVHMKYHCKTZSWYEAXJVFNSPQO

PROCEDURE    GET_METADATA    SQL_FVHMKYHCKTZSWYEAXJVFNSPQO

-- wrapper code is failing 

BEGIN 
    FOR cur_r IN(
SELECT OBJECT_TYPE,
OBJECT_NAME,
OWNER
FROM ALL_OBJECTS 
WHERE OWNER LIKE 'SQL%'
AND OBJECT_TYPE IN ('TABLE', 'INDEX', 'FUNCTION', 'PROCEDURE', 'TYPE','PACKAGE', 'SEQUENCE') 
)
   LOOP
  
get_metadata
  (cur_r.OBJECT_TYPE,
  cur_r.OBJECT_NAME);
  
  END LOOP;
END;
```

Comment: Works fine on DBFiddle: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=c4791d7d2b0e9a4a5ad6fcb9b1df1d95

Comment: Thanks!!! It must be a livesql issue

Comment: LiveSQL works fine too: https://livesql.oracle.com/apex/livesql/s/m1zobrmmusvf3iq0r9bf3eylx

Comment: But don't forget to specify `schema` parameter in `dbms_metadata.get_ddl()` since you are using `ALL_OBJECTS`, not `USER_OBJECTS`